# Is there a tool to convert a variableStep .wig to fixedStep one?

Tags: python

I have a .wig file in this format:

```
variableStep chrom=chr1 span=20
59965   7
59985   10
60005   10
60025   10
```

and I would like to format it to something like this format:

```
#bedGraph section chr16:0-103584
chr16   0       59901   0
chr16   59901   59927   1
chr16   59927   59931   2
```

Please assume, I am working with a reference hg19 genome, in case the info isn't deducible from the `variableStep` .wig file. I couldn't find anything in [WiggleTools](https://github.com/Ensembl/WiggleTools)

Comment: To me it is not obvious if these two files are consistent. What is the first position 59965 converted to ? (Perhaps it is because I'm unfamiliar with these type of files..)

Comment: @llrs they aren’t of the same data. It’s just to demonstrate the format

Comment: Could you please change one or the other so that they represent the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I had to do something similar previously, I had used the following method using `sed` and `awk`. It is not as robust in terms of error detection and correction as the python solution but it is a simple one-liner.

```
$ cat temp.wig
variableStep chrom=chr1 span=20
59965   7
59985   10
60005   10
60025   10

$ sed -r 's/variableStep chrom=(.*) span=([0-9]*)/\1\t\2/g' temp.wig \
        | awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t";OFS="\t"}{if ($1~/^chr/) {c=$1 ; s=$2} else {print c,$1,$1+s,$2}}' \
    > temp.bedgraph

$ cat temp.bedgraph
chr1    59965   59985   7
chr1    59985   60005   10
chr1    60005   60025   10
chr1    60025   60045   10
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a temporary solution I came up with that worked for my specific case:

```
def convert_line(line, chrom, span, start=None, fixedStep=None, count=None):
        new_line=''
        if fixedStep is None or count is None or start is None:
                line_arr  = line.split()
                start = line_arr[0]
                end   = int(line_arr[0]) + int(span)
                val   = line_arr[1]
                new_line = '{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n'.format(chrom, start, end, val)
        else:
                line_arr  = line.split()
                val   = np.float(line_arr[0])
                start = int(start) + int(fixedStep)*int(count)
                end   = start + int(fixedStep)
                new_line = '{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\n'.format(chrom, start, end, val)

        return new_line

def convert_file(input_file, output_file):
        chrom=None
        span=None
        fixedStep=None
        count=None
        start=None
        with open(input_file, 'r') as fin, open(output_file, 'w') as fout:
                for line in fin:
                        if len(line)<1 or line[0] == '#':
                                continue
                        elif 'variableStep' in line or 'fixedStep' in line:
                                for key in line.split():
                                        if 'chrom=' in key:
                                                chrom = key.split('chrom=')[-1]
                                        if 'span=' in key:
                                                span = key.split('span=')[-1]
                                        if 'step=' in key:
                                                fixedStep = key.split('step=')[-1]
                                        if 'start=' in key:
                                                start = key.split('start=')[-1]
                                                count = 0
                        else:
                                line_out = convert_line(line, chrom, span, start, fixedStep, count)
                                fout.write(line_out)
                                if count is not None:
                                        count += 1
```

input:

```
variableStep chrom=chr16 span=20
59965   7
59985   10
60005   10
```

output:

```
chr16   59965   59985   7
chr16   59985   60005   10
chr16   60005   60025   10
chr16   60025   60045   10
```